# How do I set a background image to mainwindow?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, background-image, qmainwindow

I am trying to set the background image of the `mainwindow` through `setStyleSheet()` but this also applies the image to its children including `textbrowsers` and `TextEdit`. How can I accomplish this without doing so?

Comment: How are you trying to set the background image ? Add the code that you have done with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add What you have tried so far,with out that we cant help.
Try the below one

```
setStyleSheet("MainWindow {background-image:url(:/files/MainPic/Technology-Banner1.jpg)}");
```